# Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

In the following code, i try to add a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header if the request comes from a specific domain.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string origin = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers.Get("Host");
    if (origin.IndexOf("blabla.com" != -1) { 
    Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }

}
```

my problem is located at this line:

```
string origin = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers.Get("Host");
```

i get the following exception :

> Exception information:  Exception type: NullReferenceException 
>   Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

I can't find what's wrong in my code.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host?

Comment: i think HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host will give the host of the page requested but not the host of the request

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I didn't understand that. So try HttpRequest.UserHostAddress https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx

Comment: Request.UrlReferrer.Host fixed my problem

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve but URLRererrer isn't "safe" because: "Gets information about the URL of the client's previous request that linked to the current URL." so it changes!

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested, there is an HttpModule you can add to the project that will
[handle this for you.](https://github.com/james-ralston/CORS.Net-HttpModule)

The problem with your code is probably that the context is null when invoked.